# How to get filtered rows in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have an  [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) with filtering option.

How to get the filtered rows (not the selected) in ag-Grid?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the forEachNodeAfterFilter(callback) api method for this.

See [https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes) for all available API calls, including the various forEachXXX methods.

Comment: Isn't there any method for this?
I must use a foreach to get this nodes?

Comment: Hi, yes, you have to iterate over the nodes I'm afraid. You'll need to build up a collection while iterating if you want to do something with the filtered nodes as a whole

Comment: anything changed since April? do we still need foreach to get updated dataset?

Answer (score 9):

Building off @sean-landsman's answer, here's an example of how to use the `forEachNodeAfterFilter(callback)` method:

```
    let rowData = [];
    gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter(node => {
      rowData.push(node.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

This took me forever so I'm posting here. Use `onFilterChanged()` to access the filtered rows, or the filtered + selected rows. The event passed to `onFilterChanged()` can be used like so (example in Typescript React)

```js
onFilterChanged = ev => {
  if (ev?.api?.rowModel?.rowsToDisplay) {
    this.setState({ selectedRows: ev?.api?.rowModel?.rowsToDisplay.filter(node => node.isSelected()) });
  }
};
```

Comment: Just fyi, `rowModel` is private, so this may change in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getSelectedNodes()` and filter() them for filtering hidden rows.

```
this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes().filter(node => node.displayed).map(node => node.data)
```

Comment: What is gridAPI. What type of data does getSelectedNodes return? NodeList? HTMLCollection? Array? JSON?

Comment: This gets the selected nodes, not filtered nodes. If the user doesn't do any row selection this returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is selectAllFiltered() function now:

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-api/?#reference-selection-selectAllFiltered