# ag-grid get filtered rows

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I've got a grid with a filter applied to it.

I have a button which selects all of the rows in the grid and performs some action. I want to retrieve the filtered rows in this method. How is this possible?

I've come across this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542110/how-to-get-filtered-rows-in-ag-grid) however this requires using a filterChanged event to maintain a copy of the filtered rows. I do not want to do this, I would prefer to just query the grid directly for the filtered rows.

Answer (score 3):

```
gridApi.getModel();
```

This will Return the row model inside the table. From here you can see the original rows, rows after the filter has been applied, rows after aggregation have been applied, and the final set of 'to be displayed' rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const onModelUpdated = (event: ModelUpdatedEvent<TData>) => {
    let newTotal = 0;
    const model = event.api.getModel();
    model.forEachNode((node) => {
      if (model.isRowPresent(node)) {
        newTotal += node.data.sum;
      }
    });
    setTotal(newTotal);
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).